# Notes Agent Full Text Index mail database on a remote server not working

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

I would like to Full Text Index a mail database on a remote domino server over an notes agent.
Unfortunately I get the following error message:

> Error 4080 - Could not FT index database
>   [*NameOfDominoServer*!!*FolderName*\*DatabaseName.nsf*]

My code is:

```
' build db connection
Dim maildb As New NotesDatabase( "", "" )
Dim cprofile As NotesDocument

Call maildb.Open(varMailServer, varMailFile)

' check if maildb is ft indexed
If Not(maildb.Isftindexed) Then
    Call maildb.CreateFTIndex(FT_INDEX_CASE_SENS+FT_INDEX_ATT+FT_INDEX_ENCRYPTED_FIELDS, True)
    db.Ftindexfrequency = 4
End If
```

What am I doing wrong or what do I have to take care about, that im able to FT index a database from a remote domino server?

When the mail database is on the same domino server, as the agent is located, the FT Index is working very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creation of a new fulltext index is only possible on the local server using this method . This is also mentioned in the LotusScript help https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_CREATEFTINDEX_METHOD_DB.html
So you basically have to create the fulltext index using an agent which runs on the same server.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Could there be a way to replicate the "database with agent" to the remote server and than run it ? Or is there a parameter option to tell on which server the agent should be run - if yes, this should be variable, because I would like to run this agent (depending on request) on few remote servers.

Comment: You can open the agent with the NotesAgent class, and use the RunOnserver method. But you must have a replica of the database on the server. Your code must open a NotesDatabase object for that replica on that server, and then use NotesDatabase.getAgent to open the agent, and then call RunOnServer.